# Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing From a Fetch Call

Tags: javascript, java, spring, rest

I want to fetch an JSONArray that includes a json and a file to my server, but i get this error

> Failed to read HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String
>   controllers.IngestController.ingestDataFile(org.json.JSONArray)

My fetch call consists of

```
var data = [
            {
                "header": headerIngestion

            },
            {
                "body": this.state.csv
            }
        ];

fetch('http://localhost:8080/ingest', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: data
            })
.then...
```

`headerIngestion` is just a regular JSON, `csv` is a csv file upload.

My server method is

```
@PostMapping(INGEST_URL)
public String ingestDataFile(@RequestBody JSONArray jsonArr) {
    System.out.println(jsonArr.toString());
    return "temporary return";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not formatted correctly so it failed to transform to JSONArray. Try this. I have not tested it myself by running it so may not be prefectly framed json but you get the point

`body: JSON.stringify({[ { header: 'headerIngestion' }, { body: 'this.state.csv' } ]})`

Comment: I thought jsonArrays start with [ and not { ?